# What values are inserted in the set with this C++ code?

Tags: c++, stl, set

I was recently given an interview question that had the following code. Unfortunately, I didn't get it right. Could someone help explain what the code is doing, especially the commented line?

Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

struct C
{
    bool operator()(const int &a, const int &b) const
    {
        return a % 10 < b % 10;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::set<int> x({ 4, 2, 7, 11, 12, 14, 17, 2 });
    std::cout << x.size();
    std::set<int, C> y(x.begin(), x.end());  // Not sure what is inserted in the set
    std::cout << y.size() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Run it and find out?

Comment: I predict `{11, 2, 4, 7}` (I didn't run the example, honest).

Comment: http://ideone.com/8eL2f4 I'm so kind

Comment: I ran it, but I couldn't properly explain why. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When run, x contains in order:

```
2 4 7 11 12 14 17
```

y contains in order:

```
11 2 4 7
```

My hunch is that the `set` reverses the operator to check for equality (since a `set` only contains unique values). Thus only unique values of `a%10` exist.

Comment: `set` doesn't use equality (as in, `operator==`). It uses equivalence, which is defined as `!(a<b) && !(b<a)` (neither element compares less than the other) or, with custom comparator, `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)`. That's how the second set ends up only with elements that are unique modulo 10.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I actually was not sure how `set` checks for equality

Comment: Thanks Igor, I think you just gave me the clue to what I should look for. The set is formed by the fact that only the unique modulo 10 values are stored. I completely did not link the fact that 2 and 12 are the same with that custom operator.